# How to configure Wi-Fi Direct P2P to connect to Android?

Tags: wi-fi

I'm struggling in connecting an embedded device to Android. Currently, I'm running on the device the following commands:

```
killall wpa_supplicant
killall hostapd
killall dnsmasq
killall dhclient
ifconfig wlan0 down
sleep 1
modprobe -r dhd
modprobe dhd nvram_path=/etc/wifi/nvram.txt firmware_path=/etc/wifi/fw.bin op_mode=1
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 10.10.10.1
cat > /tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf << EOL
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1
device_name=NAME_ON_ANDROID
device_type=2-0050F204-1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_no_group_iface=1
network={                                                                       
    ssid="NAME_ON_ANDROID"
    bssid=72:2c:1f:6c:81:49
    psk="theinout"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    mode=3
    disabled=2
}
EOL
cat /tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -D nl80211 -i wlan0 -c /tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_cli -i wlan0
    p2p_group_add
    wps_pin any 0000
    quit
```

The device appears in the Wi-Fi Direct interface of Android as 'available' with the name 'NAME_ON_ANDROID'. When I click on this name on Android, I'm invited to enter a password and I enter 0000. Then nothing happens.

How can I connect an embedded device with a fixed IP address to Android? In the config file, should device_name be the same ssid?